# Photoshop script that manipulates the window (zoom, scroll etc)

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

Is it possible to write an Abobe Photoshop (cs6) script that manipulates the window that contains the image?
For example, I would like to set the zoom level to a specific value, or change value on the scroll-bars. I have tried a lot of stuff, including the script listener, but It doesn't record the events Im talking about.

Anyone know if its possible?

Comment: has to be a way to access the scroll position, but cant figure it out yet either. Anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

for the zooming you can the following.  Base on thread [here](http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=14690&sid=53e46d7195b120982647902cfb6aeb89&sid=53e46d7195b120982647902cfb6aeb89#p14690)

```
setZoom (25);

function setZoom( zoom ) {
   cTID = function(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
   var docRes = activeDocument.resolution;
   activeDocument.resizeImage( undefined, undefined, 72/(zoom/100), ResampleMethod.NONE );
   var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
   var ref = new ActionReference();
   ref.putEnumerated( cTID( "Mn  " ), cTID( "MnIt" ), cTID( 'PrnS' ) );
   desc.putReference( cTID( "null" ), ref );
   executeAction( cTID( "slct" ), desc, DialogModes.NO );
   activeDocument.resizeImage( undefined, undefined, docRes, ResampleMethod.NONE );
}
```

Comment: That manipulates the image size, I don't the the OP wants to do that.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I have been able to set the horizontal scroll bar's offset.
Unfortunately, the document does not scroll.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Photoshop CC 2018"
        tell scroll bar 2 of front window to set value of attribute "AXValue" to 100.0
    end tell
end tell
```

I select via (java)script, want to make sure that what I selected is actually visible to the user before the script runs on. However, by now I'm close to sending trackpad events. :|